# How can I convert a midi file to wav in python?

Tags: python, wav, midi

I'm using this in Colab:

```
   !sudo apt install -y fluidsynth
   import fluidsynth
   pip install midi2audio
   from midi2audio import FluidSynth
   fs = FluidSynth()
   fs.midi_to_audio('/content/MIDI-Unprocessed_SMF_02_R1_2004_01-05_ORIG_MID--AUDIO_02_R1_2004_05_Track05_wav.midi', 'output.wav')
```

But when the procedure ends, the file does not contain any signal. If I analyze the file with librosa and pyplot I get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoWOs.png)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

When changing the extension, you're basically just renaming the file and changing the extension. In order to do that, you need to split the filename by '.' and replace the last entry by the new extension you want. You can do this using the os.rename method.

```
import os 
my_file = 'my_file.mif'
base=os.path.splitext(my_file)[0] 
os.rename(my_file, base + '.wav')
```

Comment: Thank you, but after this, for the following operation it gives me the error:  "RuntimeError: Error opening '/content/prova.wav': File contains data in an unknown format."

Comment: I'll soon find a solution for this

Comment: the code snippet only changes the name of the file, it doesn't convert it from .mid to .wav as asked

Comment: The problem is in your file explorer. You have turn on view extensions in the view tab.